# SQL how to select countries that appear every year?

Tags: sql

I have a datatable with a column "year" and a column "country".
Each country can appear more than one year, ranging from 1900 to 2021.
How to select only countries that appear in all the year (1900 to 2021)?

This is my code in selecting which is the earliest and latest year:

```
SELECT
    MIN(year) AS EarliestYear,  
    MAX(year) AS LatestYear
FROM 
    owid_energy_data;
```

Comment: Please include table columns and sample data.

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing off of Extreme_Tough's answer:

```
SELECT sub.country
  FROM owid_energy_data
 GROUP BY country
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = (SELECT MAX(year) - MIN(year) + 1
                                 FROM owid_energy_data) range
```

The purpose of the `DISTINCT` is to prevent selecting countries where for some years they appear multiple times, but are missing for other years.

Answer (score 1):

Group by country and take the count of rows. Find out if the count of rows match the number of years in the range (2021 - 1900 + 1)

```
SELECT country, count(year) from owid_energy_data
GROUP BY country HAVING count(year)= 2021 - 1900 + 1 ;
```

Comment: You don't *need* the `count(year)` in your `SELECT` if it's not going to provide anything new/useful~